# Worker process reached its allowed processing time

Tags: iis-6, worker-process, application-pool

We are experiencing this issue approximately once a month.  It is very hard to pinpoint the cause so any help would be appreciated.  This causes the App pool to stop and brings the site down.  We have gone through all log files and have concluded nothing.  We are using the 2.0.3 version on IIS 6.

Answer (score 20):

I've noticed IIS defaults web apps on a 29-hour recycle schedule, which can be troublesome since it may recycle at times your users do not expect it to.

For example: web app starts at 12 am, which means the next day it recycles at 5am, the day after that at 10am, the day after that at 3pm, etc. (this is assuming there is enough request activity against your app to keep it alive so it does not shutdown due to inactivity)

If your web app relies heavily on in-memory session state this is especially bad because the recycle will kill sessions and possibly force users to re-authenticate and lose any unsaved work. (if you don't design your app to work seamlessly with recycling)

Check the recycle schedule and make sure it recycles at a time that you expect. See this for screenshots: http://remy.supertext.ch/2010/08/iis7-worker-process-reached-its-allowed-processing-time-limit/

Not sure about the infinite loop suggestion... sounds like you just have a recycling configuration issue to resolve.

Comment: You should not attempt to do this; as you already note, there are other reasons the app pool may recycle; there's no way at all to make it recycle "at a time you expect". Therefore, you should *always* code against `Session` as if it could be wiped out on every request. Besides, this question seems to be talking about the application *crashing*, which is something different.

Comment: Let's forget about Session for a moment and focus on the issue at hand which is the app stopping at unexpected intervals. Many users who are new to IIS forget to change the default recycle interval. That message "Worker process reached its allowed processing time" is the error ASP.NET reports when it stops at a scheduled recycle point.

So, fix your recycling, set it to something predictable, then go from there.

For troubleshooting reason why app stopped, this solution from ScottGu has been very helpful to me:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx

Comment: Hmmm... where did I say to avoid reliance on Session? I said to always code as if Session could be wiped on every request. You *must* do this, no matter how you set the 'recycle interval', because you *cannot rely on when it will recycle*, no matter what you do.

Comment: Good points about Session. Note that in my original answer I wrote "if your app relies heavily on in-memory session state," but thank you for adding to the discussion on that. However, the question is about the Application stopping, not Session.

Answer (score 3):

This likely indicates an infinite loop in your application code.

Basically, every time a request comes into the web server, IIS hands the request off to a worker process.  You can configure in IIS how many of those workers there are, and what the timeout value is.  The timeout is to keep things moving in case the application code hangs -- it gets killed so the thread can go back in the pool to keep servicing new requests.

So look through your code for likely infinite loops.  Or alternatively, it could be an extremely long-running database query that could have eventually finished but exceeded the timeout value.  Perhaps your web application offers the end user an opportunity to make too broad of a query that returns too much data or requires too much DB processing time.

It's hard to give a specific cause for you, of course, but try to think along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you're experiencing a crash as a result (sounds like you are) then you might want to grab a copy of [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) and spend some time reading [Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/)' blog--she offers great advice on performing post mortem crash analysis and makes WinDbg a whole lot more approachable.